# Long text going to image backside

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I add a long text, it goes on the back of my icon.
When I try this code

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: block;
```

It's showing 2 lines only.

[image]

Comment: try to make the div of the icon as `relative`

Comment: what is the actual want then?

Comment: what i am sent image text going to icon back side. I need to text comes up 6 to 7 lines after text not going to icon back side.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following style in your CSS.

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: block;
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-word;
opacity: 100;
```